# How to change bootstrap modal animation position onclick

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I try to make Image Grid Effect such as http://tympanus.net/Development/ImageGridEffects/ and http://tympanus.net/Development/AnimatedGridLayout/ using bootstrap modal. but i cannot find the way to reveal bootstrap modal starting position from onclick image. Can someone help me please?